# In Core Data, what are valid default values for Date properties on NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data

In Core Data, what are valid default values for Date properties on `NSManagedObjects`.  In **xcode** there is a field where I can enter a default value for date properties in the model creation **gui**.  However, I cannot find an accepted value.  What values can I enter into the default value field for a date property??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I found the answer.  You can enter text into the default value for a date property of an NSManagedObject in the following format.  (In the xcode core data model creation gui.)

1970-01-03 12:00:00 +0000

Cheers!

Comment: Though we set it as an optional, why is it sill returning default date......